# Getting the Length of a Text widget

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm trying to get the length of the text inside a Text widget and `len()` does not work.

I have tried doing this:

```
variable = len(text_widget)
```

which does not work.

This is the error I am getting:

```
AttributeError: Text instance has no attribute '__len__'
```

This is the creation of `text_widget`:

```
self.text_widget= Text(self.frame1, font=("Arial", 20), fg="white", bg="#DAA520", height = 12)
```

Comment: You can try `type()` to check if it's really `str`

Comment: Could you show us the creation of your `text_widget`?

Comment: @funie200 here ```self.text_widget= Text(self.frame1, font=("Arial", 20), fg="white", bg="#DAA520", height = 12)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get the text from the widget use

```
actual_text = text_widget.get(1.0, END)
```

then you can do

```
len(actual_text)
```

Comment: Using `END` will get you one more character than the actual contents, because the text widget always adds a newline after all the text (I.e. if you type ‘hello’ you will get back a string of length 6.

Comment: @BryanOakley, that's true - good point! Of course 6 is the correct length because what you got back is 'hello\n'. You might or might not want to call strip() on it or something like that to get rid of the extra newline (and if so do that before calling len of course) - that's dependant on what you want to do with it. In the general case you get a newline and the [correct] length including it.

Comment: Sure, 6 is the correct length of what `get` returns, but it's not the correct length of what the user entered.